# MySQL missing portion of VARCHAR in query results

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running queries on the MySQL command line running Ubuntu 16.04 in a VirtualBox. Although I expect them to be the same, I get different values for the same column when running

```
SELECT * FROM enrolled;
```

and

```
SELECT cname FROM enrolled;
```

When I run the first query the cname column shows the full text, but running the second query shows only portions of the text.
The screenshot below shows what I am experiencing,
[image: missing part of query results]

Comment: can you provide sql dump of the table?

Comment: I dont think its mysql problem, rather some parsing issue. 
I noticed that you probably have the same problem in some of the last cname 

_|nt Law

|eption_

Answer (score 0):

You can try `SELECT cname FROM enrolled \G` to see if they are displayed in a row form rather than a table form.